# Using Bitwise OR in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bitwise-xor

I am working on a project where I want to toggle a value between 0 and 1 within my Mongo Database. I have set every value from the default double to a 32 bit Int. However, every time I run this code, I get this error:

```
> db.players.update({name: "Patrick Mahomes"}, {$bit: {active: {xor:1}}})
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 2,
                "errmsg" : "The $bit modifier field must be an Integer(32/64 bit); a 
'double' is not supported here: {xor: 1.0}"
        }
```

Any idea why this is occurring? When I query the active field type, it returns all of the objects in my database.

```
> db.players.find({active: {$type:16}})
```

This will end up being the functionality behind a button click on a website to toggle between two different states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers passed in the mongo shell are deduced to be `double` to match javascript-style conventions. So the `1` in `{xor: 1}` is a `double`.

You'll need to specify `NumberInt(1)` to get a 32-bit integer (or `NumberLong(1)` for a 64-bit integer).

This behavior is documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/data-types/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to provide value with **NumberInt**.

```
db.players.update({name: "Patrick Mahomes"}, {$bit: {active: {xor:NumberInt(1)}}})
```

Check document [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/)

Comment: I didn’t cast the number I was xor’ing. Great thanks